# What happens if the pins of two different usb thumb drives touch each other?

Tags: usb, flash-memories

What happens if the pins of two different usb thumb drives touch each other?

Can the data get corrupted?
Can the data move from one drive to another?
Can the circuits get damaged?

Comment: Are you aware that USB thumb drives require a 5 V supply to operate?

Comment: i know there are two power lines at the outermost ends; +5V  and -5V; but what if they touch each other miliseconds after being unplugged from a computer port, and have some sort of residual energy inside them?
edit: forgot to say thank you for your answer. thank you for your answer.

Comment: The contacts are recessed inside the connector - it would take serious effort to make contact between the contacts of two connectors.

Comment: thank you, also i think i should thank to designers of usb connectors :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely nothing happens if two otherwise unpowered USB drives touch one another. As with all electronics, one needs to have voltage applied with some current flowing for the device to function.

If there's no power, nothing happens.

Comment: thanks for your answer, very helpful for me. but what if they touch each other miliseconds after being unplugged from a computer port, and have some sort of residual energy inside them? is this possible?

Comment: no, it's not possible that they would be damaged by that (within reasonable limits of possible)

Comment: thank you for your answer. i really appreciate.

Comment: USB thumb drives are considered _devices_, or in old parlance, slave. The thumb drive can't poll. It would take a _host_, or in old parlance, master, to poll the _device_ whereupon data can be transferred. A millisecond is a very short time span - just pulling out the flash drive would be tens of milliseconds.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i really appreciate.